# Add php delete button to foreach upload statement

Tags: php, forms, variables, submit, delete-file

I am using a foreach php statement to list all of the uploaded files within a directory.
It looks like this:

```
<?php 
$path = "$dir/";
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) {  
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);  
    $result = $path_parts['filename'];  
    echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>";
}
?>
```

This prints out a nice simple list of all files.
What I would like to do for each item, is add a delete button next to it. I am thinking the only way to do this, would be to add a form into the `foreach` statement, with just a button that posts the `$filename` variable to some PHP with the delete function in.

The only thing I am uncertain of is if the best way to get the filename to the new php.

I am thinking along the lines of:

```
<?php 
$path = "$dir/";
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) {  
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);  
    $result = $path_parts['filename'];  
    echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>";
    echo "<form method='post' action='delete.php'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";                
}
?>
```

So using that, I can create a button next to the filename for deletion, but the only way I can think of taking the actualy filename through to the delete PHP file, is to add in a hidden text field with the filename as the value.

This would work but seems a bit clunky. Can anyone advise if this is acceptable or if there is a better alternative?

Comment: Is this secured? It looks like a pretty vulnerable way of getting to your files...

Comment: this is more of a test at the moment. I am building a company intranet, and this is more or less proof of concept. i doubt any sensitive information will be stored here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of the filename/id/whatever to the form is not really that clunky .. it's more of a necessity unless you want javascript to be mandatory (then you can get the filename from the sibling `li` or something.  However, there are a couple problems:

### HTML

You have a random `tr` tag (should this be `br`) at the end of each list.  Your `li` are outside of a `ul` or `ol` block, and the `form` must be inside of an `li` (that is you cannot have `<ul><li /><form /></ul>` as valid markup).  Not a huge deal, but this may cause some display problems for you.

### UI

It would be pretty annoying to have to click individual "deletes" on a long list of files, and it looks like there is no way to recover from this.  Even better would be to have them be check boxes so you could delete multiple files at once and change your mind before your final decision.  Then, you only need one form and it makes even more sense to have individual inputs for each file.

### Security

I'm not sure how you get `$dir` (I really hope register globals isn't on), but you should make absolutely certain that requested file deletions contain a valid path to delete and preferably don't contain `../` or a leading `/` or something.  You should validate this input.

Comment: thanks for your answer! as for the markup itself, it is rough and was copied straight from a previous answer to a question, and I have yet to correct this. as for the UI, I completely agree, this would be a much better solution, and I think that will be what my ultimate goal is. $dir is simply just an absolute path, with one folder in the pathname changed, based on the user ID.

Comment: also, the directory must exist, as in the preceeding php at the top of this same page, is code to check if the directory already exists, and if not, to create it

Answer (score 0):

A hidden field with the file name would suffice, you can use php's $_POST to get the filename in the other script. Another option would be to post it to the script using a get parameter with the filename, so you only change the get parameter part.

The real problem is that you should sanitize the input the second script receives. It is just very important that people can only delete files they're allowed to delete.
At the very minimum you should check if the file is in a specific folder. Other options are only deleting files from one folder (so not accepting paths) or abstracting filenames away behind id's

Comment: at the moment, the $dir variable is based on the user ID that is currently logged in. The directory varies user by user, so hopefully there shouldnt be any cross deletion, and it should only be deleting from that user's folder.

Comment: As long as you take good care with that, either the hidden field or the get parameter will do just fine.